# SCCM: Where can I find the ccmsetup.exe or .msi installer for download?

Tags: sccm

I'm trying to setup SCCM on a remote machine running Windows 10 and I need to know where to download the SCCM setup from, other than extracting it from a server ISO or something like that.

Context: The machine in question is a regular PC that has been installed by my company in another firm's organization to run our proprietary software and act as a server, and we have full remote access to it via RDP and a VPN, but from that server PC, we'd like to remotely control and manage a second PC (also ours) that's a client to the server PC, for maintenance purposes.

Our customer is a hospital and is very picky about remote access on second-tier PCs such as this client PC; they won't even let us install UltraVNC on it.

The only way we can maintain our software on this PC would be by actually sitting in front of it, and that's not a viable solution.

Both machines are supplied by us and run our own Windows 10 ghost with all the necessary software on them; the server PC hosts our proprietary applications, and the client connects to the server PC to access the applications and read/write data in an SQL database that's part of our software package.

The server PC has access to the Internet through the client's organization proxy, but the client PC doesn't.

My question is, Where can we download ccmsetup.exe or ccmsetup.msi from, so that we can deploy it on our server PC, and from it remotely manage the client PC while staying within the client's security guidelines?

RDP is not an option because it would mean the people using the client PC would have to let us disconnect them to connect in their place, when what we really want is to observe the issues and problems they encounter while using our software.

Ideally, we'd use UltraVNC, but as I mentioned earlier, this customer won't allow that.

Basically, all I need is a download link for the x64 and/or x86 SCCM setup files.

I've searched the Web for it and found lots of entries on how to fetch the console install files from a local server and install them, which I already know how to do, but no direct download link to a Microsoft repository.

Any help to that effect would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SCCM 2016/2019 evaluation downloads are available, but that isn't going to help you. It most likely needs to be the package they use for installation, as there are prerequisites such as AD membership and certificates.

Comment: @GregAskew thanks for your reply. The PCs in question aren't the client's but our own, therefore they are treated by the client as guests since they are not part of their organization. Certificates could be a factor in this mixed environment, indeed. Still, we'd really like to give it a try.

Comment: I don't see this happening unless you run their installer.

Comment: I'll check that out tomorrow when we contact them. Thanks for your time and your input!